# How can I warp/resize/translate the windows desktop output?

Tags: windows-7, image-processing, desktop

I saw this video [(YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgrGjJUBF_I) and I want to make use of the ability shown at 3:00. Can anyone tell me what is being used here? Ideally suggestions would work on Windows 7 at least.

I've had a few google searches for "Active Windows Desktop", which was mentioned in the video, in an attempt to finding something that has this feature but I failed at finding anything

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you look into WPF -- it has built-in features for arbitrary transformations of window content, so it would probably be a good place to start looking.

Comment: Would that work for ANY windows screen, not just an application developed in WPF?

Comment: I think you would have to create a WPF application that 'copied' the desktop and drew it onto a fullscreen application. Then you could warp the window using a transformation matrix. I've never written such a thing, but I'm guessing it would be easiest to do using WPF.

Comment: I've thought about this a bit more, and I think perhaps OpenGL would be a better alternative. I believe you could 'capture' (using a FrameBuffer) the Windows desktop and store it as an image which you could then map onto an arbitrarily-warped polygon.